# Difficult gstreamer pipeline - Decode/demux h264 file to jpeg on Windows using DirectShow

Tags: jpeg, directshow, h.264, gstreamer

I've been trying for days to get gstreamer's gst-launch-1.0 to output an h264 stream as individual jpegs, but want only one per second, and using the DirectShow hardware acceleration.  I've tried numerous iterations of commands, and this is the closest I've gotten:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.h264 ! decodebin ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=1/30 ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=img%03d.jpg
```

This gives me 300 jpegs from my 10 second h264 stream, and it doesn't use the DirectShow hardware interface.

I've used `gst-inspect` to try to use what I thought was the DirectShow decoder for h264 (`video/x-h264`) but that gives me errors.  I've also tried to change the framerate from 1/30 to 30/1 and 1/1, but always get the same 30 jpeg per second output.

I thought `decodebin` was supposed to automatically select the best decoder based on the input stream, but it appears to be using a CPU intensive one (instead of GPU hardware-accelerated) judging by how the CPU on my test machine pegs at 100% for the duration of the `gstreamer` process.

Ideally, I'd also like the jpegs to be output at a different resolution than the resolution of the video, but everything I've tried (width=640,height=480) either causes errors or doesn't result in a resized jpg.

Comment: I know how to do all this with `avconv`, but it also is CPU intensive and I'm trying to free the CPU to perform other tasks during the decoding process.

Comment: My test system has an ATI Radeon Xpress 1250 card in it and the system says it is running DirectX 9.0c.  According to specs, the X1250 has DirectX 9 in hardware.  I don't know when h264 decoding was added to DirectX, but I'd assume it was in well before DirectX 9.

Comment: Changing the output resolution is easy, just add a videoscale element and then set the desired caps after that. In terms of using a DirectShow decoder, you will need to have that as a GStreamer-element in order for that to work. gst-inspect will allow you to see that plugins you have on your system, and then you can further gst-inspect these to see the "features" (elements) of these plugins and their capabilities. Maybe pastebin an output from running just gst-inspect, and I can take a look what your options are?

Comment: Havard Graff: Thanks for the offer.  I've switched my development platform to Ubuntu 13 running on ODROID-U2 hardware.  Here is a pastebin of my gst-inspect-1.0 - http://pastebin.com/2jNFFCuS

Comment: I don't know how to identify what is a hardware decoder and even if I knew what that was, I don't know how to get gstreamer to use it.

Comment: Using the pipeline I stated above, gst-launch-1.0 pegs 1 CPU at 100% for 22 seconds to decode a 10 second 1080p h264 stream into 300 1920x1080 JPGs.  I decode to ramdisk to minimize I/O latency issues.  I'm hoping to minimize the CPU usage and use the GPU if at all possible so I can decode multiple streams simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's an easy way to do this as pre-baked pipeline. However you can write a probe that counts frames and drops say 29 out of every 30 (e.g. increments a counter % 30). I'm guessing you are wanting to generate thumbnails/previews from a video here?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use this to create thumbnails from a video.  BTW, if there is anyone knowledgeable in gstreamer-1.0 and wants to earn a little money, I'd be willing to work out a deal for them to help me do this.

Comment: ...Well, not just this, but everything I listed in my original question.